# Load a Flat file(.txt) in SSIS Simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I am having a scenario where I need to load a Single Flat File(abc.txt) with the count of records in different table.
e.g: 
Package 1 : is having a Data flow task which will get the count of records from table 1 and load it in a Record set. Then Record set value will be written to abc.txt using flat file connection manager.

Package 2 :is having a Data flow task which will get the count of records from table 2 and load it in a Record set. Then Record set value will be written to abc.txt using flat file connection manager.

Package 3 :is having a Data flow task which will get the count of records from table 3 and load it in a Record set. Then Record set value will be written to abc.txt using flat file connection manager.

Now I have a master package which will call Package 1, Package 2 and Package 3 with 3 different execute package tasks(Execute Package Task 1,Execute Package Task 2,Execute Package Task 3). The Execute Package Task will be running in parallel. 
When I am running the package the execute package tasks(either 1/2/3) got failed saying can not open file abc.txt. Is it only because I am trying to write same destination file simultaneously from different packages or is it for any other reason?  Is there any way so that  different package can simultaneously write on same destination flat file?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating the packages independently from eachother, i.e. without a master package, and run the Three packages in a sequence using for instance SQL Job Agent, ensuring that the previous package has been completed Before the next package commenses?

Answer (score 0):

All the three packages are trying to write in the same file in parallel. It is not possible to write in same destination flat file from multiple sources simultaneously.
Instead of writing the record count directly to flat file, you can consolidate all the record counts in a variable and write the value of this variable to the flat file only once.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you :) Please mark as answer as it may help others too!